# Generar una canción a través del PWM de una BBBK

Tags: python, sonido

Tengo una Beagle Bone Black y quiero activar el modo PWM para poder generar sonidos con un piezzo buzzer.

Lo estoy intentando hacer con una librería de Python llamada Adafruit, pero no suena nada. Las conexiones están bien hechas, lo que dudo es si hay que configurar previamente ese pin para decirle si es de tipo PWM o algo así.

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.PWM as PWM
myPWM="P8_13"
PWM.start(myPWM, 25, 1000)
time.sleep(2)
PWM.stop(myPWM)
PWM.cleanup()
```

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

EDITO: Funciona perfectamente, el piezo buzzer estaba roto.

Comment: ¿Estas controlandolo con un Arduino o que micro?